# Issue with hyperlinks in HTML, CSS for Google Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have created a website for a guesthouse. www.excelhome.co.in
In it I have 4 hyperlinks in the menu bar and all of them works fine in the home page. But the same hyperlinks don't work in any other pages and this issue is only with Google chrome.

Below is the hyperlink code:

```
        a.one
           {
              color:#ddd;
                  text-decoration:none;
           }

        <td align="center"; style="width:10%;">
                 <a class="one"; href ="Index.htm">Home</a>
        </td>
```

With all other browsers all pages and links work fine.

Comment: www.excelhome.co.in
 is the website

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon from within the a (anchor) element, it is invalid and may well be causing problems.

Looking through the source code and validation summary (see http://validator.w3.org/), the majority of errors are related to misplaced semicolons within element declarations. There are also a number of obsolete attributes used which should be replaced by CSS properties (either using an inline style attribute, or external stylesheet).

I only have a tablet with me at the moment, so can't inspect in more detail, but you certainly want to look into how you manage your layout - the twenty-four non-breaking spaces should probably be replaced with margin or padding for example.

Comment: If it was causing problems, then it would be causing them on all the pages.

Comment: @Quentin That depends on the consistency of the code as it is used throughout the site - but point taken. I only have a tablet with me at the moment, so can't inspect properly, so will have to defer to you for a full diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

You've covered the links up with a massive, positioned element with `id="Layer1"`. The clicks aren't reaching the links because they are being intercepted by it.

Absolute positioning is something that should be used with a very, very light touch.

Comment: I tried removing layer1 itself...but the issue still remains. and it's happening only with Google chrome...with IE it is working fine.

Comment: You appear to have removed the `id` attribute without removing the element. When I delete the element from the DOM using my browser's developer tools, the links become accessible.

Comment: The links are working fine for me in Home page. In which page did you tried it. Also how it's working in other browsers.

Comment: The About Us page. As I said, deleting the element fixed it. It wouldn't have fixed it if I couldn't have reproduced the original problem.

Comment: @user3280292 If Quentin's answer solved your problem then you should accept it (the green tick) and/or vote it up to help future users with the same problem.